# Material Design Light Waterfall Header

Tags: jquery, material-design-lite

I am trying to replicating the waterfall header that is shown in the demo template file for `Material Design Light`: https://getmdl.io/templates/portfolio/index.html (try scrolling)

I feel like I have copied pretty much the same `HTML`, I don't see any custom `script` other than what comes with `MDL`... but my header is not collapsing.

If I manually apply  `is-casting-shadow is-compact` classes to my header they do collapse and I can certainly pound out some `jQuery` to do this easily enough, but I want to understand what is causing it to collapse here without any custom `js`.

I found more info at the details site:
https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section
but after digesting it, I see nothing that I'm doing wrong, it's just not adding the `is-compact` class to my header when I scroll...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using script? 
I think the code to add class is written in the script file

```
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, I am certainly doing that